# Python: How to install a third-party package and make it available to rest of team

Tags: python, git, installation

My team uses git to track the code and we want to do the following: (1) One team-member installs a third-party python package and (2) makes it available on our git repo, so that the rest of the team can simply install the package by pulling the latest version of our code.

Is that possible at all? If so, what are feasible solutions? If not, what approach works best in your experience?

Background: We are using python 2.7.*. The third-party package is testfixtures to unittest the logging of our software. We use Windows and Mac.

Comment: Are you using something like [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)? This is the problem it's meant to solve.

Comment: @Chris Yes, now I use `pip`. It works well if the access rights are set appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a requirements.txt file and place it in your directory.  Each line in the file should contain the name of a package that your entire team should have installed.  Your team members, once they have the new version of the file, can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Then, update the requirements.txt file every time you have a new package required, and rerun the command.

Some editors (like PyCharm) will even automatically detect a requirements file and prompt you to install the packages.

Comment: I followed your instructions, incl. the PyCharm recommendation. The installation is executed. However, it creates an error: `could not create 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\testfixtures': Access is denied`.

Comment: To solve the access problem, I set the access rights of the `Lib` directory to read, write and modify for a normal user.

Comment: Or, execute it as sudo: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`